# How to write a point-in-polygon query for Postgis?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, polygon

I'm trying to write a query in Postgis which will return all rows where a dynamically changing longitude/latitude point resides within the geometric polygon of that row (in the `geom` column). This is the query I'm trying to use:

```
SELECT * FROM "geospatial-data" 
WHERE ST_Contains(
    "geospatial-data".geom,
    ST_Transform(
        ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-90.56210 38.60369)', 4326), 4269
    )
)=true
```

I'm basing this query off of an older post here: http://codemagician.wordpress.com/2009/09/12/point-in-polygon-in-postgis/

I'm not getting any errors but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. How should I write/modify the query in order to query for a point-in-polygon?

Comment: that one return true when given point is in given geospatial-data geometry.  so it work like intended

Comment: Really? I thought it will select everything where the "WHERE" condition is true. It shouldn't be returning true, instead, it should be returning the rows of data where the condition equals true. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Well, it does return those rows (`=true` is not needed really). So if you're not getting data you want the problem is with data.

Comment: you also might want to provide a link to your polygon data

Comment: Perhaps the SRID of "geospatial-data" is not 4269 in your data.

Answer (score -3):

It works to me when i avoid the mismatch SRID's.  SRID's must be identical